# Not able to add custom domain in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce-communities

I have setup a community for one of our client and trying to add a domain for it in Administer | Domain Management | Domain. Everytime, I try to add domain name as 'testcommunity', it gives me below error

Error: Salesforce.com can't validate the domain. The CNAME record may still be processing (which can take up to 24 hours), or the domain may not belong to you. Make sure the domain name 'testcommunity' uses testcommunity.****orgid****.live.siteforce.com as its CNAME target and try again later.

We added a CNAME in DNS Management three days before and it has propagated successfully. Check on 'www.whatsmydns.net' and it shows  CNAME is correctly pointing to testcommunity.****orgid****.live.siteforce.com

It seems to be a bug to me as we followed the help & training tutorial for same and followed all steps. Please can anyone help us out in this.